# Is it true that $\mathbf{P} (X \leqslant t) =\mathbf{P} (F (X) \leqslant F (t))$ for continuous $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

For continuous $X$ with distribution $F$, is it true that $\mathbf{P} (X \leqslant t) =\mathbf{P} (F (X) \leqslant F (t))$? Also is continuity required?

I've attempted a proof:

Since $\mathbf{P} (F (X) \leqslant F (t)) =\mathbf{P} (X \leqslant t, F (X) \leqslant F (t)) +\mathbf{P} (X > t, F (X) \leqslant F (t)) =\mathbf{P} (X \leqslant t) +\mathbf{P} (X > t, F (X) = F (t))$

it is sufficient to prove that $\mathbf{P} (F (X) = c) = 0$ for some fixed $c$.

If $c = 0$ and $F$ attains 0, then $u := \sup \left\{ t : F (t) = 0 \right\} < \infty$ with $F (u) = 0$ by continuity. To see this, if $F (u) = \epsilon > 0$ then by MVT there is a $u^{*} < u$ s.t. $F (u^{*}) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and $F (t) = 0 \Rightarrow F (t) < F (u^{*}) \Rightarrow t < u^{*}$ and $u^{*}$ is an upper bound, contradiction. Now $\mathbf{P} (F (X) = 0) \leqslant \mathbf{P} (X \leqslant u) = F (u) = 0$. The case for $c = 1$ is similar.

If $0 < c < 1$, then $l := \inf \left\{ t : F (t) = c \right\} < \infty, u := \sup \left\{ t : F (t) = c \right\} < \infty$, and $F (l) = F (u) = c$ by continuity. Now $\mathbf{P} (F (X) = c) \leqslant \mathbf{P} (l \leqslant X \leqslant u) = F (u) - F (l) = 0$.

Comment: The equality is true for any monotone function...

Comment: @d.k.o.: I doubt it is true for a decreasing function

Comment: @Henry Cool, got a proof anywhere?

Comment: @Henry Oh, sure. I meant  monotonically increasing function.

Comment: @Henry: what do you mean by "weakly increasing"? If it is "non-decreasing", it it not the case, is it? (consider $F$ being a constant function, for instance)

Comment: @ClementC. Good point. I will remove my original  comment

Comment: Hint: Is it true that $\{X \leqslant t\} =\{F (X) \leqslant F (t)\}$?

Comment: @Did Well there's $\Rightarrow$ but not $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: Sub-hint: And when can the second inclusion fail?

Comment: @Did well it works when $F$ is strictly increasing, so I guess that covers some non-continuous distributions. Would it work for any discrete ones?